# How to call a function and return a different value in haskell? (W/o monads)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am having issues figuring out if this is possible. Any pointers would be awesome

I'm not sure on the exact syntax but something like

```
m = 3
d = putStr "d"
f = d ; m
```

Such that it would call function `d`, and return the value in `m` without being `Maybe m`?

**EDIT:**

What I am looking for is more like this?

```
eval s = s
m = 3
f = (eval s) ; m
```

Comment: What do you want `eval` to actually do? I mean, if you discard the return value, what's the point of running it at all?

Comment: The phrase "call a function" suggests that you are thinking about Haskell functions the wrong way. Haskell is both *pure* and *lazy*; "call" implies strictness and impurity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call a function wrapped in a monad (IO in this case), then you must also be in the IO monad. Thus are the rules of monads - never to be broken.

```
m :: Int
m = 3

d :: IO ()
d = putStr "d"

f :: IO Int
f = do d -- Teehee, doodie.
       return m
```

Comment: So I guess I used a terrible example.  What about this

eval s = s
m = 3

f = (eval s) ; m

basically evaluate some value, and return a different value?

Comment: @sampwing: Why do you want to evaluate the value? If you're not composing effects, the best it can do is make your computer hot. (Apart from some cases, where you need to do this to avoid excessive laziness; use `seq` in those cases). Or perhaps you're looking for `Debug.Trace.trace`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to debug your program in `printf`-like manner, use the `Debug.Trace` module.

Otherwise see Clark Gaebel's reply above — you can't¹ get pure (non-`IO`) values out of an `IO` function, and `putStr` is only possible in `IO` functions.

---

¹ actually sometimes you can, but it's a complex matter